# Elements of order 5 in $S_7$, odd permutations of order 4 in $S_4$, and find a specific permutation in $S_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

$(1)$ How many elements of order $5$ are in $S_7$(symmetric group)?

$(2)$ How many odd permutation of order $4$ does $S_4$ have?

$(3)$ If $\beta \in S_7$ and $\beta^4=(2143567)$ then find $\beta$

Give me some hints for these three questions.please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints (for you to prove/use)

i) The order of a permutation expressed as a product of disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of the cycles' lengths (orders) , and therefore

ii) A permutation has prime order iff it is the product of disjoint cycles of that prime length

The above must get you going with (1)-(2). As for three, use

(iii) The powers of a cycle of odd length are again cycles of that length.

Comment: (1)there are 504 elements of order 5 in $S_7$? is my ans. correct?

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the number...nice! +1

Comment: please check ans. in my question.

Comment: (2) ans.6 is this correct ....but for last que.(3) give me some idea.

Comment: can u give what is the exact value of $\beta$?

Comment: No, I'll leave that to you, but just pay attention to the fact that if you have the odd cycle $\,c:=(1\,i_2\,i_3\,...i_r)\,$ , then upon squaring it the numbers "jump" two places: $\,c^2=(1\,i_3\,i_5\ldots i_r\,i_2\,i_4\ldots i_{r-1})\,$

Comment: ok thanks i will try and then give u the last ans.

Answer (score 2):

for first one i tried that,

(1) the possibility for $5$ length cycle is $lcm(5,1)$ and $(1,5)$

let (a b c d e) be cycle of length $5$ the to arrange this we have $7$ element so,

```
 7.6.5.4.3=2520
```

and the repeatation will be $5$ because $(abcde)=(bcdea)$ etc.

so $ \frac{2520}{5}=504 $

(2) similarly i got ans. of (2) is 6

(3)Ans. $(2 4 5 7 1 3 6)$

Answer (score 1):

1. What kind of cycle structure leads an element of $S_7$ to have order $5$? and how many elements are there with that cycle structure?
2. What kind of cycle structure leads an element of $S_4$ to have order $4$? Are elements with such cycle structure(s) even permutations, or odd?
3. What could the cycle structure of $\beta$ possibly be?

Answer (score -2):

Solution of (3):

$$\beta^4=(2143567)$$
Now $$\beta^7=(1)$$
    $$\beta^4 \beta^3=(1)$$
  $$(2143567)\beta^3=(1)$$
     $$\beta^3=(1276534)$$
Since
    $$\beta^4=(2143567)$$
    $$\beta\beta^3=(2143567)$$
     $$\beta=(2143567)(1276534)^{-1}$$
     $$\beta=(1362457)$$